# Craft Commerce Subscriptions

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

We're using commerce 3.2 and were testing the plans options with the default templates.  We've put in the Stipe test keys, but when we try to subscribe, we get the message:

Unable to start the subscription. Please check your payment details.

Is there anything we've overlooked?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see some information about the payment failure in the event logs in Stripe, if you check the Product or the Customer pages and look for the logs.

One gotcha that's happened to me a few times is because of tax rate IDs not being set correctly between Craft and Stripe. In my case it's usually because I've pulled down a database dump from production which has production tax rate IDs set, and I'm using it in my local environment which is using test Stripe API keys and *should* be using test tax rate IDs but I've forgotten to switch them over.

If you're using a tax rate, it might be worth checking to see if it's set up correctly both in Stripe and in Commerce. That can definitely cause this error to show up.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your help,  There wasn't anything unusual in the logs.  But when we tried this on the live site rather than the dev environment, it seems to work ok.  I guess it's a difference in the environments.